# How to generate .env file for laravel?

Tags: laravel, installation, composer-php, laravel-5, environment

From the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/master#install-composer) I see it's possible to create a laravel project
via laravel installer:

```
$laravel new blog
```

or via composer:

```
$composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

If I try the first way .env file is not created.
How can I ask laravel,artisan or composer to create a .env file for me?

Comment: You should at least have a `.env.example` in there. Is it possible that you just don't see the file because it's hidden? (starting with a `.`)

Comment: What is your OS? if its linux then the dot(.) file by default in hiddem state. Please show the hidden files you will get the `.env` and `.env.example` file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had this problem of no .env files showing up in the project.

Turns out the IDE I was using (Netbeans, try not to judge) will show certain types of .hidden files but not all.

After racking my brains for a bit I checked the file system and found the .env + .env.example files / modified them with a text editor.

Leaving this answer for the rare situation someones using a dodgy IDE like myself.

Comment: yes man, that was my problem either. Nice IDEs finish last.. :D

Comment: The questions asks how to *generate* not show, but since this is marked as the correct answer, I have added an answer that tells you how to show the .env in Netbeans rather than exit to use another IDE.

Comment: @Popnoodles Yes, and this answer was just pointing out other potential problems that might afflict the asker. Frankly, the quick fix was using a notepad editor at the time - but I didn't even know if OP was using Netbeans or not - it could have been any other IDE with a similar issue. The best answer for this question here is by limonte, as OP hasn't edited his question to make it Netbeans specific.

Answer (score 82):

Just tried both ways and in both ways I got generated `.env` file.

Composer should automatically create .env file. In the `post-create-project-cmd` section of the `composer.json` you can find:

```
"post-create-project-cmd": [
  "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
  "php artisan key:generate"
]
```

Both ways use the same `composer.json` file, so there shoudn't be any difference.

I suggest you to update `laravel/installer` to the [last version](https://github.com/laravel/installer/releases): 1.2 and try again:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.2"
```

---

You can always generate `.env` file manually by running:

```
cp .env.example .env
php artisan key:generate
```

Comment: What about when I do not have laravel/installer on my composer.json? Just laravel/framework at require and laravel/homesead at require-dev... =/ - but creating it manually works well.

Comment: thank yo, I needed it when I clone a project from my repository to another system and it worked great.

Answer (score 30):

In windows OS, you can open command prompt, change directory to your project directory.
Example,
My project directory

```
E:\xampp\htdocs\my_project
```

You can type into your Command prompt like this (hit enter each line):

```
E:

cd xampp\htdocs\my_project
```

Then you can type,

```
copy .env.example .env
```

If you are using Linux, you can type ***cp***, instead of ***copy***

Answer (score 18):

If the `.env` a file is missing, then there is another way to generate a .env file

You can download [**env.example**](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example), rename it to `.env` and edit it. Just set up correct DB credentials etc.

Don't forget to When you use the `php artisan key:generate` it will generate the new key to your `.env` file

Comment: Please specify where to place this file.

Comment: The **root directory** of your application will need to have a `.env` file, You can keep it there

Answer (score 17):

In console (cmd), go to app root path and execute:

```
type .env.example > .env
```

Also can use:

In Windows:

```
copy .env.example .env
```

In Linux/Mac:

```
cp .env.example .env
```

Answer (score 3):

`.env` files are hidden by Netbeans. To show them do this:

Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Files

Under Files Ignored be the IDE is Ignored Files Pattern:

The default is

```
^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(?!(htaccess|git.+|hgignore)$).*$
```

Add env to the excluded-not-excluded bit

```
^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(?!(env|htaccess|git.+|hgignore)$).*$
```

Files named `.env` now show.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but as it still gets viewed and recently active "26" days ago as of this post, here is a quick solution.

There is no **.env** file initially, you must duplicate **.env.example** as **.env**.

In **windows**, you can open a **command prompt** aka the **CLI** and paste the exact code below while inside the **root directory** of the project. Must include the **(** at the start line without space.

```
(
echo APP_NAME=Laravel
echo APP_ENV=local
echo APP_KEY=
echo APP_DEBUG=true
echo APP_URL=http://localhost
echo.
echo LOG_CHANNEL=stack
echo.
echo DB_CONNECTION=mysql
echo DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
echo DB_PORT=3306
echo DB_DATABASE=homestead
echo DB_USERNAME=homestead
echo DB_PASSWORD=secret
echo.
echo BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
echo CACHE_DRIVER=file
echo SESSION_DRIVER=file
echo SESSION_LIFETIME=120
echo QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
echo.
echo REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
echo REDIS_PASSWORD=null
echo REDIS_PORT=6379
echo.
echo MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
echo MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
echo MAIL_PORT=2525
echo MAIL_USERNAME=null
echo MAIL_PASSWORD=null
echo MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
echo.
echo PUSHER_APP_ID=
echo PUSHER_APP_KEY=
echo PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
echo PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
echo.
echo MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
echo MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
)>".env"
```

Just press enter to exit the prompt and you should have the `.env` file with the default settings created in the same directory you typed above `CLI` command.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

create .env using command!

composer run post-root-package-install
or
sudo composer run post-root-package-install

Answer (score 1):

If you have trouble viewing the *.env* file or it is not showing up in the project just do this: `ls -a`.
This allows to see the hidden files in Linux. You can also open the folder with Visual Studio Code and you will see the files and be able to modify them.

Answer (score -1):

There's another explanation for why `.env` doesn't exist, and it happens when you move all the Laravel files.

Take this workflow: in your project directory you do `laravel new whatever`, Laravel is installed in `whatever`, you do `mv * ..` to move all the files to your project folder, and you remove `whatever`. The problem is, `mv` doesn't move hidden files by default, so the `.env` files are left behind, and are removed!

Answer (score -1):

copy any  .env.example file of any Laravel project and create  .env.example file in your Laravel directory, then paste it in the file you just created, copy this code below and open your terminal, in your project directory, paste it, wait for your project to be updated, see everything working again. thank you.

composer install
mv .env.example .env
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
php artisan key:generate