# Can't open Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-artisan

Installed php7.2, composer, laravel 2.0.1,on Ubuntu 16.0

Every time i create new project

```
 $ laravel new TestProj
```

a lot of "reccomandations" shows up:

> symfony/var-dumper suggests installing ext-intl (To show region name in time zone dump)
>   symfony/routing suggests installing doctrine/annotations (For using the annotation loader)
>   symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/config (For using the all-in-one router or any loader)
>   symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection (For loading routes from a service)
>   symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using expression matching)
>   symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/yaml (For using the YAML loader)
>   symfony/event-dispatcher suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
>   symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/browser-kit ()
>   symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/config ().......

but I've read that it's ok,

now, when I try to start the server

```
TestProj$ php artiasn serve
```

it starts ok:

```
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
```

but when I try to enter this address in browser(same on firefox and chrome) the page says "woops, it's seems like something went wrong", and in the command line is written:

```
[Fri Feb  9 00:54:59 2018] 127.0.0.1:52176 [200]: /favicon.ico
```

Tryed to write this in index.php:

```
<link rel="FaviconIcon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: have you tried localhost:8000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue might be that your `APP_KEY` is missing, solution to this is to run `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: ErrorException  : file_get_contents(/home/valeriu/Desktop/blog4/.env): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
  at /home/valeriu/Desktop/blog4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/KeyGenerateCommand.php: 96
  92:     {
  93:         file_put_contents($this->laravel->environmentFilePath(), preg_replace(
  94:             $this->keyReplacementPattern(),
  95:             'APP_KEY='.$key,
  96:             file_get_contents($this->laravel->environmentFilePath())
  97:         ));
  98:     }
  99: 
  100:     /**
  101:      * Get a regex pattern that

Comment: will match env APP_KEY with any random key.

  Exception trace:

  1   file_get_contents("/home/valeriu/Desktop/blog4/.env")
      /home/valeriu/Desktop/blog4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/KeyGenerateCommand.php : 96

  2   Illuminate\Foundation\Console\KeyGenerateCommand::writeNewEnvironmentFileWith("base64:abwRwRp2a+2RGdc1y0vh+0su421lYFDE5RBMW9JliUA=")
      /home/valeriu/Desktop/blog4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/KeyGenerateCommand.php : 80

Comment: Can you check do you have a file named `.env` under `/home/valeriu/Desktop/blog4/`, if you don't create it

Comment: @Altaris? See this to learn how to create a .env file https://stackoverflow.com/a/29915688/3566757

Comment: It worked! But `[Fri Feb  9 16:18:23 2018] 127.0.0.1:35226 [200]: /favicon.ico` is sill apearing

Comment: You are then missing more `environment variable` i would suggest you go to this url: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example and copy the contents of it, and then run the command `php artisan key:generate` again @Altaris

Answer (score 0):

You need to give writing permission to your storage files

```
sudo chmod 777  storage/
```

Comment: doesn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy

blog4/.env.example

to

blog4/.env

After that  you can run the:

`php artisan key:generate`