# Failed to open stream: .env

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I want to start a Laravel application, but when running `composer install`, it can not find the .env file. Nor does it create one.

I thought it was a path url problem, because there are slashes and the backslashes provided in the path url.

Here is the output:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postInstall

> php artisan key:generate
```

Gives error:

> [ErrorException]
>       file_get_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\tekom-web/.env): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>
> Script php artisan key:generate handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1

Comment: You say "not does it create one", that sounds like it actually doesn't exist so are you sure you have a .env file?

Comment: key:generate doesn't create an env file.  You should already have one,  either create one or copy the .env.example file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.env files are gitignored by default and not included in version control due to many reasons, including security of project and API keys. Therefore, when you clone a Laravel application, you won't have one by default and you can not use an artisan command to create one.

The best solution is to copy the .env.example and rename it to .env, then use the artisan key:generate command and it should work! The reason I suggest copying the example .env file is that, if you cloned this project, developers often use the example env and include all necessary environment variables right out of the box. By copying it, you ensure consistency with the project requirements.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the directory in which your project was created, in the creation command it should have created an example `.env` file for you. But [sometimes thins can go worng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915514/how-to-generate-env-file-for-laravel). If you cloned a project in your machine it does not create one really. Either way, you should always check your environment related files when starting to work on a new environment ;)